# Urql useQuery - How to clear data on query / variables changes?

Tags: reactjs, urql

**How can I configure the hook so it won't return the data from the previous query while it fetches the new data from the network or cache?**
Something like a parameter `keepPreviousData: false`.

If you dynamically change variables, or query, of a `useQuery()` hook, the result will still contain the previous data while fetching for the new one.
While it is very useful for infinite scroll patterns, it is less for queries that change dynamically like for a search interface. In such interface, user would not like to see deprecated results that doesn't match anymore his search query.

For sample:

```js
const [search, setSearch] = useState('');

// The hook will fetch data matching the search variable typed by the user
const [result] = useQuery({
  query: "...",
  variables: {search}
});

// If the search variable changes,
// result still contains data from last query
//  while fetching new search
const data = result.data;


return (
  // user types and changes the search variable
  <TextInput onChangeText={setSearch} />
);
```

PS: I would also reward the bounty to someone who made a PR for such a feature, if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score -1):

As per [the documentation for `useQuery`](https://formidable.com/open-source/urql/docs/api/urql/#usequery),

> The result is an object with the shape of an [`OperationResult`](https://formidable.com/open-source/urql/docs/api/core/#operationresult) with an added `fetching: boolean` property, indicating whether the query is being fetched.

Therefore, it should be enough to check if `result.fetching` is true:

```jsx
function SearchForm() {
    const [search, setSearch] = useState('');

    // The hook will fetch data matching the search variable typed by the user
    const [result] = useQuery({
        query: "...",
        variables: { search }
    });

    const data = result.data;

    return <>
        <TextInput onChangeText={setSearch} />
        {
            !result.fetching && result.data
            ? <SearchResults data={result.data} />
            : null
        }
    </>;
}
```

Comment: I need to choose to keep the data or not. Sometimes I wanna keep the data like for infinite lists, where I'll just change an offset variable.

Comment: @Yairopro Then… choose? Where is the problem?